# Git pull from other user than in config

Tags: git, github, git-pull, git-config

I have repository created and the following `config` file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://user@github.com/repo/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "develop"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/develop
```

Now when I use `git pull` I get notification to input password for `user` but I don't know this user password. However I know password for different user and this user has access to this repository. Is it possible to run `git pull` to enter different user than in `config` file not modifying this config file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your user as well

```
git config [--global] user.name "Your Name"
git config [--global] user.email "your@email.com"
```

Then GitHub will ask for the credentials for that user.

Also, it's considered better (and simpler, and safer) to generate SSH keys and define them on the remote repo.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I've done it (without `--global`). Now I have in `config` file also section `user` with my Github user name and email assigned to this account. But when I simply run `git pull` I still get prompt `Password for user@github.com/repo/repo.git` and not for my user.